# Write an algebraic expression in terms of $x$ (where $x > 0$) for "$\tan(2 \tan^{-1} x)$"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write the following as an algebraic expression in terms of $x$ (where $x > 0$):

$\tan(2 \tan^{-1} x)$

This is what I got so far:

Let $\tan^{-1} x = \theta$. So, $\tan(\theta) = x$.

So, opposite = $x$, adjacent = $1$, and hypotenuse = $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$.

So, $\tan (2 \tan^{-1} x)$

$ = \tan (2\theta)$

$= (2 \tan(\theta))/(1 - \tan^2(\theta))$.

Now I'm stuck. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta = \tan^{-1}x \to \tan(2\theta) = \dfrac{2\tan \theta}{1-\tan^2 \theta} = \dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}$

Comment: Thank you!!!   sometimes my brain just shuts down; today is one of those days.

Comment: You might want to accept this answer if you find it useful. If so , click the "green button" .